# Deserializing complex DTO in WCF has null List<T>

Tags: c#, wcf

We recently upgraded our solution from Asp.Net 4.0 to 4.5.1 and now we're getting errors when deserializing some complex DTOs. In all cases, the DTO has a `List<T>` property that is not being initialized, and the deserialization fails when trying to add objects to the collection. I have made sure the getters and setters initialize the property like this:

```
[DataMember]
public List<objBusinessActivityGroup> BusinessActivities
{
   get { return m_groupList ?? ( m_groupList = new List<objBusinessActivityGroup>()); 
}
set {
      m_groupList = (value != null) ? new List<objBusinessActivityGroup>(value) : new List<objBusinessActivityGroup>();
}
}
```

but this has no effect. We have also added the `[OnDeserializing]` attribute to each of the parent and child DTOs to try and initialize these properties, still no help. We have gone through all of the classes and interfaces and made sure that each `[ServiceContract]` attribute has a `Namespace` value, and that all DTOs have `[DataContract]` attributes with the same `Namespace` settings. I added some code that makes a log entry when the `[OnDeserializing]` callback is hit, and can see where the callback is being invoked, but as the timing of when the callbacks are invoked is not guaranteed, I can't say if they are invoked in time for the deserializer to add items to the respective collection.

The complete environment is a WinForms application that accesses WCF services secured by a custom STS.  Like I said, all was fine until we upgraded the web services solution to 4.5.1. The WinForms application is still using v4.0 Client Profile, and at this time we can't change that.

This is the exception we're getting:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 was unhandled by user code
>     HResult=-2146233087
>     Message=The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://sure.amc.faa.gov/ws:far. The InnerException message was 'The get-only collection of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[GlobalServices.Objects.objFABusinessActivity, GlobalServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' returned a null value.  The input stream contains collection items which cannot be added if the instance is null.  Consider initializing the collection in the getter.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
>     Source=mscorlib
>     Action=http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher/fault
>
> StackTrace:
>       Server stack trace: 
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>       Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>          at Services.WebServices.FundingAgreementService.IFundingAgreementRepository.SaveRevision(objFundingAgreementR far, Boolean issubmit, Int32 userid)
>          at Services.WebServices.FundingAgreementService.FundingAgreementRepositoryClient.SaveRevision(objFundingAgreementR far, Boolean issubmit, Int32 userid) in c:\Projects\SURe_Client_1_5\Services\Service References\WebServices.FundingAgreementService\Reference.cs:line 4519
>          at Services.Models.IAAModel.DoSaveRevision(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in c:\Projects\SURe_Client_1_5\Services\Models\IAAModel.cs:line 1192
>          at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
>     InnerException:

What this is saying is, the parent DTO (the far) has a property of type `List<objBusinessActivityGroup>`.  Each `objBusinessActivityGroup` has a property of type `List<objFABusinessActivity>`.  When the deserializer goes to add items to the `List<objFABusinessActivity>`, it is null.

This is how we are initializing the collection:

```
[DataMember]
public List<objFABusinessActivity> BAList
{
    get
    {
        if (_baList == null)
        {
            _baList = new List<objFABusinessActivity>();
         }
         return _baList;
    }
    set {
            _baList = (value != null) ? new List<objFABusinessActivity>(value) : new List<objFABusinessActivity>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Full exception details is always recommended.  Call ToString on it, then paste the result in an [edit].

Comment: Added exception text to my question.

Comment: Have you tried simply initializing the backing field for for the `List<objFABusinessActivity>` that turns out to be null?

Comment: @BartoszKP The code sample above shows how we are initializing the property in the getter and setter.  When WCF is desrializing, it casts the data to the correct type; it does not create a "new" object, so the constructor has no say in the matter.  Is this what you are referring to or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You didn't call ToString on it.  Otherwise, "Please see InnerException for more details." would have included the inner exception.  Also, the callstack.  Good luck.

Comment: @MichaelCaruso No. 1) The code you've shown is for `List<objBusinessActivityGroup>` but the error concerns `List<objFABusinessActivity>`. 2) The object WCF is casting has to be created anyway, so if the field was not initialized it will be `null` when deserializing - hence my suggestion to initialize it.

Comment: I'm getting the exception info from running the client application in debug mode; it's the only way I can get this information as the exception is occurring during deserialization so my error-trapping code in the WCF service doesn't come into play.  The InnerException in this case is being included.

Comment: @MichaelCaruso The error says about a "get-only collection". I'm not sure what that means, but since the code you've posted has both `get` and `set` the question arises: are you sure that these are the relevant pieces of code?

Comment: @BartoszKP In our schema, the only List<objFABusinessActivity> is in the objBusinessActivityGroup class, so yes, I'm pretty sure this is the correct code.  Unless I'm misreading the exception somehow.

Comment: @MichaelCaruso Try and go ahead with Will's suggestion. The other inner exception might have some important details.

Comment: Updated the exception info; this is all I get.

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider to apply Data Contract Know types? It allows you to specify, in advance, the types that should be included for consideration during deserialization. See more details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
[KnownType(typeof(List<objFABusinessActivity>))]
[DataContract]
public class YourDtoClass
{
   [DataMember]
   public List<objFABusinessActivity> BAList
   {
     get
     {
        if (_baList == null)
        {
            _baList = new List<objFABusinessActivity>();
         }
         return _baList;
     }
     set 
     {
            _baList = (value != null) ? new List<objFABusinessActivity>(value) : new List<objFABusinessActivity>();
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: We already had declarations for the base objects, like [KnownType(typeof(objFABusinessActivity))], but I added declarations for the List<T> types too.  Unfortunately it did not help.  Same error message.